# Basic auth must be preemptive with protobuf converter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, protocol-buffers

As explained in [this blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services) we can use ProtobufHttpMessageConverter to serialize/deserialize Protobuf messages. When using basic authentication, if I choose the JSON media type with the protobuf message converter I can use preemptive auth or not, it doesn't matter. However, if I choose the protobuf media type I **must** use *preemptive authentication* otherwise it does not work, i.e., the server returns an unauthorized response as expected but then the basic auth response does not seem to be processed. However when I switch on preemptive authentication, i.e., the basic auth response is sent right away, it works as expected. Nonetheless, this seems rather strange to me. Does someone know why?

You'll find below a sample code that reproduces the issue. Simply access the web service using [REST Client](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) for instance.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ProtobufHttpMessageConverter protobufHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new ProtobufHttpMessageConverter();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test").password("test").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(
                        SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}

@RestController
class CustomerRestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    Data.Customer customer() {
        return customer(5, "Toto");
    }

    private Data.Customer customer(int id, String f) {
        return Data.Customer.newBuilder()
                .setId(id)
                .setName(f)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And the Protobuf message data.proto:

```
package demo;

message Customer {
    optional int32 id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
}
```

Here's the logs I get when *not* using preemptive auth with the following request header: "Accept:application/x-protobuf". You can notice that after the unauthorized response nothing happens (the basic auth response should be processed).

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5576e87d
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@79376d4e, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@4e65575
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

You can compare this with the following logs which come from a request without preemptive auth but with the following request header: "Accept:application/json". You can notice that after the unauthorized response, the auth response is processed by the server and the expected JSON representation is returned.

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5576e87d
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@79376d4e, returned: -1
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@4e65575
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Tue Apr 14 14:41:15 CEST 2015, status=401, error=Unauthorized, message=Full authentication is required to access this resource, path=/}] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@5d603063]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@5576e87d
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'test'
o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442bd3dc: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442bd3dc: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@6c2f0571
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/' matched by universal pattern '/**'
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@442bd3dc: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@364492: Username: test; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@79376d4e, returned: 1
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [demo.Data$Customer demo.CustomerRestController.customer()]
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'customerRestController'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [id: 5, name: "Toto"] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter@42d2b7d8]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: I think a little more information is needed. You state "otherwise it does not work", but this is not very informative. What doesn't work? What does your client look like? What does the HTTP request look like? What does the HTTP response look like? What do you expect the HTTP response to look like?

Comment: I've added more details. Hope it can help.

Comment: It sounds as though the server side is working just fine since it is sending back the appropriate response. The problem seems to be with the client code. Can you post the code for creating the client and for using the client?

Comment: It's not about the client code, it's about using preemptive auth or not. Again using preemptive authentication works just fine. The issue happens when **not** using preemptive authentication, i.e., the behavior changes upon the accepted media type, which seems rather strange. One can get the issue using any client as long as preemptive auth is not used. Use for example [REST Client](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/) or a programmatic client using RestTemplate.getForEntity(...) or any other.

Comment: Sorry I had misread the logs and thought the client was simply not responding to the HTTP 401 status code. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue in Spring Boot. I created [spring-projects/spring-boot/issues#2827](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2827).

**What is happening?**

This happens because [BasicErrorController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/BasicErrorController.java#L70) is creating an `ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>`. When `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` attempts to write the body, it cannot because `ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` [only supports writing protobuf Message objects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.java#L97).

**Working around the issue**

The issue can be handled by creating a custom Controller to process the errors. For example:

```
package demo;

option java_package = "demo";
option java_outer_classname = "Data";

message MapFieldEntry {
    required string key = 1;
    required string value = 2;
}

message Error {
    repeated MapFieldEntry errors = 1;
}
```

Generate the respective Java classes. Then create a controller:

```
package demo;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import demo.Data.Error.Builder;
import demo.Data.MapFieldEntry;

/**
 * @author Rob Winch
 */
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    @Autowired
    public ErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error", produces = "application/x-protobuf")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Data.Error> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> body = getErrorAttributes(request, getTraceParameter(request));

        Builder errorsBuilder = Data.Error.newBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> error : body.entrySet()) {
            demo.Data.MapFieldEntry.Builder entryBuilder = MapFieldEntry
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setKey(error.getKey())
                    .setValue(String.valueOf(error.getValue()));
            errorsBuilder.addErrors(entryBuilder.build());
        }
        Data.Error errors = errorsBuilder.build();
        HttpStatus status = getStatus(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<Data.Error>(errors, status);
    }

    private boolean getTraceParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String parameter = request.getParameter("trace");
        if (parameter == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return !"false".equals(parameter.toLowerCase());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request,
            boolean includeStackTrace) {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        return this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes,
                includeStackTrace);
    }

    private HttpStatus getStatus(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        if (statusCode != null) {
            try {
                return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        return HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
}
```